# Default username password for CUPS

Tags: 16.04, printing

What is the default admin username and password for CUPS linux printer configuration?

Answer (score 21):

```
username: {your username to enter the pc}

password: {your password}
```

Comment: Worked for me (on a mac platform)

Comment: Worked for Linux 18.04 as well. Thanks!

Comment: As trivial as useful! Thanks! Works on Ubuntu 20.04 too.

Comment: Thank you.......

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add you user to cups group
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PrintingCupsWebInterface

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1224619)